# how to write increment document get element by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
  <div class="form-group col-md-12 input_fields_wrap">
          <label for="merk">Merk</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="merk[]">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary add_field_button" type="button">add row</button>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div id="1"></div>
        </div>
```

**above my html code and when i click add row will append new row with id="2" **
and this is my javascript code

```
function validasiForm(){
    var y = document.getElementsByName('merk[]').length;
    console.log(y);
    for (var i = 0; i < y ; i++) {
        var merk = document.getElementsByName('merk[]')[i].value;
        if (merk == null || merk == "") {
        document.getElementById("i").innerHTML="<p class='color-red'>*validation message</p>";
        // document.getElementById("merk2").innerHTML="<p class='color-red'>*nama merk harus di isi</p>";
          return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

---

so my question is how to dynamically show validation message with dynamic get element by id?

Comment: Well for a start `document.getElementById("i")` isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Why do you have a jQuery tag when you're not asking a question about jQuery?

Comment: i use jquery for append

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("i")` is literally looking for an element with the ID "i". Use a different naming convention, like "elem1" or something. Then `document.getElementById("elem"+i)`.

It's worth mentioning that IDs should not begin with numbers anyway. This will cause an error as a variable name in javascript (IDs are implicitly global variables) and CSS will ignore it. It might never cause you pain, but hey-- good to know.

Comment: document.getElementById("merk"+i).innerHTML="<p class='color-red'>validatio message</p>"; like this?

Comment: id="merk1",id="merk2"

Comment: Yep, that should do it.